# File is not listed in directory, but can be written and loaded from there with Python / Pandas. An environment issue?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, environment, hidden

Python 3.6.4; Windows 10. And now also Anaconda / Python 3.7.
T
his has me COMPLETELY baffled.

This code loads the file, and prints the first row of a csv file:

```
    import pandas as pd
    city_data = pd.read_csv("c:\\YelpData\\Data_PA.csv",usecols=range(1,11),encoding='latin-1')
    print(city_data.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
user_id                       Kn_02c9-Jkpm3nakKk9mbg
business_id                   54rjpC8YuM3QN_QbFGmLAg
city                                         Belmont
postal_code                                    28012
categories      Restaurants;Italian;Sandwiches;Pizza
stars_b                                          3.5
review_count                                      51
stars                                              2
date                                      2012-06-09
useful                                             3
```

BUT, that file is NOT listed in that directory:

```
C:\YelpData>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is ************

 Directory of C:\YelpData

02/26/2020  09:44 PM    <DIR>          .
02/26/2020  09:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/26/2020  11:27 PM             3,513 DatasetManipulation.py
02/26/2020  09:44 PM        31,409,942 yelp_business.csv
09/26/2019  10:24 AM     3,791,120,545 yelp_review.csv
02/26/2020  09:39 PM     3,791,120,547 yelp_review_mod.csv
               4 File(s)  7,613,654,547 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  87,651,495,936 bytes free

C:\YelpData>
```

I thought the csv file I was creating wasn't being written to this directory, but it is, in some strange dimension.  Is this some crazy Pandas environment issue?  I am not familiar with this language, I was just trying to write some code to join two csv files.  Based on the output above my join works - **I just need the actual physical CSV file** - so I can do analytics on it with a different product.  (I placed the two lines of code above at the TOP of my python program, and then ran it from a Windows command prompt.  So it is loading that invisible file first.)

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE

As requested, here is the code which creates the csv file.

```
filename="c:\\YelpData\\Data_PA.csv"
filex = open(filename, "w")
DataPA.to_csv(filex)
```

I originally tried it this way. (I just tried this with the new "\\".)

```
DataPA.to_csv("c:\\YelpData\\Data_PA.csv")
```

I also renamed the outputfile to Data_PA1.csv in the code, with the "\\" change, in case it was somehow using the old file in someone unknown location/environment.

UPDATE

I have pretty much determined this is some kind of strange environment issue.

1. I can't write the csv file to a non-existent directory. (Expected.)
2. I can write the csv file to an existing directory, then delete that directory, and then continue to be able to read the file from the deleted directory (the Python program can). (!!!) (Not expected.)
3. I can add a file to the directory, with the same name, with 0 size (Data_PA.csv), and Python continues to read the file it previous wrote (to somewhere) (!!!) (Not expected.)

UPDATE

I uninstalled Python, and installed Anaconda (which includes Python).  The results are the same.

Comment: Does `dir /AH` show the file?

Comment: It's not a problem in this case, but generally its a good idea to use python raw strings (`r"c:\YelpData\Data_PA.csv"`) or forward slashes (`"c:/YelpData/Data_PA.csv"`) with Windows path names. ` \ ` is a python escape character and for instance `\t` is a tab character, not a subdirectory.

Comment: @tdelaney - No, the file is not hidden.

Comment: Hmmm.  It's been 40 minutes since I posted this (and 2 hours since it drove me mad).  Now I'm worried about this.  Inexplicable.  I'll get back at this tomorrow.

Comment: you could check in Python `os.listdir("c:\YelpData\")`. You could also check in `c:\` if you don't have two folders with similar names

Comment: Is there anything odd about your environment? Running in a VM? Or remotely on a jupyter notebook? Something that would make a C drive a different asset?

Comment: Not that I know of.  And I'm the only person using this laptop.  I haven't installed any VM or Jupyter.

Comment: This gives an error - EOL while scanning string literal   ----   os.listdir("c:\YelpData\")

Comment: @Mike_983 - you got hit by the use of backslash as an escape character. Any of `r"c:\YelpData\" , "c:\\YelpData\\" , "c:\YelpData" , "c:/YelpData/"` should work

Comment: I tried the \\ idea when Answer 1 was posted.  I get the same results.  Also, that explanation doesn't account for the contents of the file be correctly written and read.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was Comodo Firewall.  At some point Auto-Containment had gotten turned on.   My shadowed files were in a mirrored directory structure under c:/VTROOT/...  Along with a lot of other stuff I don't want in there.  I have disabled Auto-Containment.  Google shows many people have ran into this.

I know when I installed Comodo over 1.5 years ago that I didn't set that, as I didn't want it.  At some point a checkbox got inadvertently set.  Well, now I know how it works.